# how to connect eos smart contact with flutter app

Tags: smart-contract, dapp

flutter has this package name **Eosdart**,Im able to get the detail from blockchain with app like account detail,but im unable to push the transaction.

I want to push a transaction which carry argument along with it and then store those arguments into the EOS table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:eosdart/eosdart.dart';

main() {
  EOSClient client = EOSClient('http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'v1',
      privateKeys: ["5J9b3xMkbvcT6gYv2EpQ8FD4ZBjgypuNKwE1jxkd7Wd1DYzhk88"]);

  List<Authorization> auth = [
    Authorization()
      ..actor = 'bob'
      ..permission = 'active'
  ];

  Map data = {
    'from': 'bob',
    'to': 'alice',
    'quantity': '0.0001 SYS',
    'memo': '',
  };

  List<Action> actions = [
    Action()
      ..account = 'eosio.token'
      ..name = 'transfer'
      ..authorization = auth
      ..data = data
  ];

  Transaction transaction = Transaction()..actions = actions;

  // will print something like:
  // {transaction_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, processed: {id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, receipt: {status: executed, cpu_usage_us: 216, net_usage_words: 16}, elapsed: 216, net_usage: 128, scheduled: false, action_traces: [{receipt: {receiver: eosio.token, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576794, recv_sequence: 17, auth_sequence: [[bob, 37]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 73, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: [{receipt: {receiver: bob, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576795, recv_sequence: 14, auth_sequence: [[bob, 38]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 2, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: []}, {receipt: {receiver: alice, act_digest: 117d5840be4ff21fad764d5d497182916f76e772b279e65e964bccfa7c888331, global_sequence: 576796, recv_sequence: 15, auth_sequence: [[bob, 39]], code_sequence: 1, abi_sequence: 1}, act: {account: eosio.token, name: transfer, authorization: [{actor: bob, permission: active}], data: {from: bob, to: alice, quantity: 0.0001 SYS, memo: }, hex_data: 0000000000000e3d0000000000855c340100000000000000045359530000000000}, context_free: false, elapsed: 2, console: , trx_id: c28bf8c168741adb96f3aef8723e953140cc60ecd20cec0d22e5a2dc5cdd5571, block_num: 576745, block_time: 2019-05-03T06:07:54.500, producer_block_id: null, account_ram_deltas: [], except: null, inline_traces: []}]}], except: null}}
  client.pushTransaction(transaction, broadcast: true).then((trx) {
    print(trx);
  });
}
```